# Unix commands not working on terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm not able to execute any unix commands on my Mac OS Terminal. I was adding a path to my Scala Installation Location.

[image]

Comment: You'll have to restore your path variable some how. If you just set the variable in one terminal window, just start another one and the path should work. Otherwise you'll need to figure out what PATH should be on your system.

Comment: I don't get it. Open another terminal window and open the .bash_profile? It gives me the same error on top of the window. "-bash: export: `Setup/Languages/scala-2.10.3/bin:??': not a valid identifier"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've broken your `$PATH` environment variable, by the looks of it in `~/.bash_profile`.

To fix:

- Start Terminal.app (with error message as you posted).
- Manually set `$PATH`:

  ```
  export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
  ```
- Edit your `~/.bash_profile`:

  ```
  vi ~/.bash_profile
  ```
- Remove the `??` characters from the scala path. That looks like it might be an invisible character, so I would recommend deleting the line and retyping it.
- Save and test.

Comment: when i entered ~/.bash_profile it says " Permission denied" Please help i'm not able to enter a single line of code also

Comment: You will never understand how much this saved me!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've replaced your path, rather than appended the path to Scala. You'll now need to use the full path to commands and then you'll be able to restore the path.

You can call vi from /usr/bin/vim